# how to create a sp that inserts values from one table to another

Tags: sql

Hi I want to create a stored procedure that takes specific values from one table and inserts them into another if a specific table been 'DateAquired ' is null I have this stored procedure below but it doesn't seem as expected please help.
 Thanks in advance

this is my code

```
USE [MediaPlayer]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Wishlists]    Script Date: 11/26/2013 11:43:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Wishlists]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Name nvarchar (250),
    @FileName nvarchar (250),
    @FilePath  nvarchar (50),
    @FileSize float,
    @DateAdded date,
    @MediaLength nvarchar (50),
    @MediaSubType nvarchar(50),
    @MediaType nvarchar(50),
    @Thumbnail image,
    @DateAquired nvarchar (50),
    @WishList int output ,
    @CName nvarchar  (50)output ,
    @Media nvarchar (50)output,
    @WishListID int output

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
Select GeneralID, Name, FileName, FilePath,FileSize,DateAdded,MediaLength,MediaSubType,MediaType, Thumbnail,DateAquired As Wishlist 
From General where NULLIF(DateAquired,'')IS Null

insert into Wishlists (generalID ,MediaType, Name)
values ((IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.General')),(IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.General')),(IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.General')))
SET @WishListID = @@IDENTITY
select GeneralID, MediaSubType, Name

From General where NOT EXISTS (Select Name from WishLists Where Name =@Name);
END
```

Comment: `IDENT_CURRENT` and `@@IDENTITY` are hardly ever the correct functions to use. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY` and difficult to know what you are attempting with the three `IDENT_CURRENT` calls but under conditions of concurrency it certainly won't do what you want.

Comment: 1. You do not use any of your input parameters apart from @name. 2. Your insert statement to `Wishlists` appears to be unrelated to anything else in the procedure, you are just inserting the last identity from `general` to all three columns, but you don't actually change any data in `general`. 3. Do not use `@@IDENTITY` to get the identity of values just inserted. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: In addition saying *"but it doesn't seem as expected"* isn't helpful without elaborating on what you were expecting. Explain what you expected to happen (i.e. what you are trying to achieve), and also what is happening that you weren't expecting (i.e. what is going wrong).

Answer (score 0):

try below insert statement

```
insert into Wishlists (generalID ,MediaType, Name)
select GeneralID, MediaSubType, Name
From General where NOT EXISTS (Select Name from WishLists Where Name =@Name);
```